# Twitter API 1.1 friendships/create rate limit

Tags: twitter

I'm moving my application from Twitter API version 1 to 1.1 and have issues with friendships/create.

according to the 1.1 documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/friendships/create) friendships/create is not rate limited, yet when I call friendships/create I can see that the rate limit is 15 (according to 'x-rate-limit-limit').

Am I doing something wrong here? is the rate limit really 15 follows per time window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran found the solution:

> I use the twitter gem and when you call follow it first makes a call to friends/ids to make sure you are not already following that member and /friends/ids is limited to 15 calls per window.
>
> the solution was to call `follow!` (with ! ) instead to avoid the check.

From here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14894

Comment: Hey the link isn't active anymore. Can you show the code which you used to make the call? I am unable to follow people using the API.

Answer (score 0):

According to the new Twitter API documentation on [creating friendships](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/post-friendships-create):

> If the user is already friends with the user a HTTP 403 may be
>   returned, though for performance reasons this method may also return a
>   HTTP 200 OK message even if the follow relationship already exists.